# Passing NSArray Pointer Rather Than A Pointer To a Specific Type

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've just written a piece of code to display a UIActionSheet within my app.  Whilst looking at the code to initialise my UIActionSheet something struck me as a little strange.  The initialisation function has the following signature...

```
initWithTitle:(NSString *)title delegate:(id UIActionSheetDelegate)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles
```

As you can see the otherButtonTitles parameter is a pointer to a String.  In my code I set it as follows...

```
otherButtonTitles: @"Title", @"Date", nil
```

Although this compiles fine I don't really understand how it works.  My reading of the statement is that I have created an inline array containing two elements (Title and Date).  How come this then compiles?  I'm passing a NSArray* in place of a NSString*.  I know from a little of understanding of C++ that an array is really a pointer to the first element. So is this inline array that I'm creating a C array as opposed to a NSArray?

What I'm hoping to achieve is to be able to pass a static NSArray* used elsewhere in my class to the otherButtonTitles parameter.  But passing the NSArray* object directly doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no NSArray involved, and the method signature you quoted is incomplete. The actual signature is

```
… otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...;
//                                               ^^^^^
```

The `, ...` indicates [**variadic function** (varargs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which means arbitrarily many arguments may be supplied after `otherButtonTitles`.

This is a C feature. The called function can receive the arguments using methods in [`stdarg.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h). Since ObjC is a superset of C, varargs is supported for ObjC methods as well, using the `, ...` as shown.

For example, varargs is also used in `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` and `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` (which may be your confusion that an "array" is passed).

---

If you have an NSArray, you could insert the buttons after the action sheet is created using `-addButtonWithTitle:`.

```
for (NSString* title in array)
   [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately it looks like XCode's code completion didn't indicate the var args argument - that's where I copied it from.  I've come across the concept before in Java so it all makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with arrays.  You are using the basic ANSI C functions for variable arguments.  Look up `va_list`, `va_start` and `va_arg`.